# Auto reply from the use of a predefined word list

Tags: python

My over all goal is to have it where when a message contains a word from a predefined list it will auto respond with a message. I have been trying to start simple and have it respond if first word is in the list but i keep getting "first arg must be str, unicode, or tuple, not list. Be nice im new to python and am trying to learn. So im not only looking for the answer but also direction on how and whats going on.

```
import discord
import random

from jokes import * 
from badwords import * 

client = discord.Client()
client.login('username', 'password')

@client.event

def on_message(message):
    # we do not want the bot to reply to itself
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('~guildwebsite'):
       client.send_message(message.channel, 'website {}!'.format(message.author.mention()))

    if message.content.startswith('~who'):
       client.send_message(message.channel, 'I am the Phoenix Chat Butler{}!'.format(message.author.mention()))

    if message.content.startswith('~bdo'):
       client.send_message(message.channel, 'https://www.blackdesertonline.com/ {}!'.format(message.author.mention()))

    if message.content.startswith('~cmd'):
       client.send_message(message.channel, '~guildwebsite, ~who, ~bdo, ~help, ~tellmejoke'.format(message.author.mention()))

    if message.content.startswith('~help'):
       client.send_message(message.channel, 'The help that you need I cannot give! {}'.format(message.author.mention()))

    if message.content.startswith('~tellmejoke'):
       client.send_message(message.channel, random.choice(joke_list).format(message.author.mention()))

    if message.content.startswith(bad_list):
       client.send_message(message.channel, 'Please keep the language down! {} 
@client.event
def on_ready():
    print('Username')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run()
```

---

This is the code from the file its importing

```
bad_list= ['word',
'keeping',
'clean',
'pg13']
```

Comment: Message is presumably a list, and should be a string.

Comment: What does a `message` look like when the `on_message` function receives one?

Comment: Is this your exact code? Because your 'Please keep the language down!' string never terminates. I'd expect this code to crash immediately with `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal`.

Comment: @kevin i did leave off the rest of the line following the "language down!" .format(message.author.mention())) is to finish that line. thanks for pointing that out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if message.content.startswith(bad_list):
```

`startswith` does not accept a list as a parameter. If you want to determine whether `content` starts with any element of `bad_list`, use `any`.

```
if any(message.content.startswith(word) for word in bad_list):
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That took care of stage one and i understand what the code is doing. Now what direction do i need to look into for it to be able to pull a substring (i think its called). So if message is "Hello, this word is not good." It see "word" which is in list, and responds. BTW eventually the response will be sending timeout and ban commands to the chat client which is where it is getting the message.content from. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you only want to see if a bad word is _in_ the content, rather than seeing if the content starts with a bad word, use `if any(word in message.content for word in bad_list):`. Incidentally, this may not be the best approach for censoring text. See [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem) for more information.